# stuck with gmail api

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I followed the instructions in this link 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php
I did everything as they request
untill the end , the problem now what to do after the php quickstart.php when I do it it only lists

```
 php quickstart.php labels  -INBOX
Labels:
- DRAFT
- CATEGORY_UPDATES
- UNREAD
- CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS
- INBOX
- CATEGORY_SOCIAL
- CATEGORY_PERSONAL
- CATEGORY_FORUMS
- TRASH
- CHAT
- IMPORTANT
- SENT
- STARRED
- SPAM
```

and when I put quickstart.php in the browser I got this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This application must be run on the command line.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail-api\quickstart.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmail-api\quickstart.php on line 12
```

I want to list the messages in my app 
Thanks to everybody will help

Comment: Have you tried doing this example?: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Comment: The Google example says to run `quickstart.php` from the _command line_, **not** from the browser. Once you run it from the command line, the output gives you a URL to enter into your browser to authenticate.

Comment: @khaleader, Can you please answer your own question for people searching for this same problem?